# new object in c++

Tags: c++

i'm new to c++ programming and i will be happy if you can help me.
i tried to write this code:

```
bool RailwayLineList:: AddInTail(const RailwayLine& data)
{
    //there is no linked list to add the element
    if(this==NULL)
        return false;
    RailwayLineLink *newLink =  new RailwayLineLink(data);
}
```

when i tried to debug it i saw that the copy constructor had been called and the data had been initialized with some garbage (the class is using a default constructor).

why is the copy constructor being called?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. In future, when you write code you should highlight it and click the button with binary on it; this will format it so that it will appear properly. :-)

Comment: Without seeing the `RailwayLineLink` constructor you are using it's hard to say but it sure looks like "because you asked for it to be".  Put a breakpoint on the empty copy constructor (which class are you questioning about, by the way?) and check the callstack to be sure.

Comment: @Platinum Azure: WTF?! I added spaces manually to every line of code I wrote!! ;(

Comment: The expression `this == NULL` inside a member function doesn't make sense.  If `this` really was `NULL`, you wouldn't even be able to call the member function without invoking undefined behavior.  Also, you're leaking memory here by losing your pointer to the new `RailwayLineLink` object you allocate.

Comment: I've corrected your post to make it more readable, but in the future, please mind your spelling when creating a question. Also, it is rather hard to answer your question because relevant parts of the code are missing.

Comment: @BlackBear: I used to do that too, for at least a year of my membership here! But I heard someone else talking about it recently and I've (largely) come around. :-)

Comment: @Platinum Azure: Oh, I'm pleased to see I'm not the only fool around! Do not be offended, I'm just kidding ;)

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing more of your code, but my guess would be that the `RailwayLineLink(data)` constructor makes a copy of `RailwayLine`, which is where the copy constructor is being called.  Also, note that a default constructor will not initialize any fields that don't have a constructor, which is why they are "garbage".

Comment: Just a little thing, not all your codepaths return a value. if `this!=NULL` (which it incidentally is), the result is undefined.

Comment: @BlackBear: No offense taken; I know you were joking.

Answer (score 2):

A copy constructor is a constructor with a specific signature.  It takes a single parameter, of const reference to the same type being constructed.  So for a `class Foo`, the copy constructor looks like this:

```
Foo::Foo(const Foo&)
```

There are 2 other kinds of constructors: default and convert.  The default constructor takes no parameters (or can be called as if it took no parameters, eg, all parameters have defaults):

```
Foo::Foo()
```

...and the convert destructor is basically anything else.  For example:

```
Foo::Foo(const Bar&)
```

---

> why is the copy constructor being called?

In your case, you're calling a `RailwayLineLink` constructor but passing in a const reference to a `RailwayLine`, so you're actually calling a convert constructor, not a copy constructor.

The convert constructor is called because you called it:

```
new RailwayLineLink(data);
```

This constructs a new `RailwayLineLink` object, passing `data` as the one and only parameter to the constructor.

If you have an empty convert constructor, that looks something like this:

```
RailwayLineLink::RailwayLineLink(const RailwayLine&)
{
}
```

...then all of the members of the new copy will be default constructed, and probably contain garbage.

Typically when you implement a copy constructor, you would want to do some kind of memberwise copy from the original to the copy, like this:

```
RailwayLineLink::RailwayLineLink(const RailwayLine& rhs)
: value_(rhs.value_)
{
}
```

Comment: Look carefully... the `data` parameter is actually of type `const RailwayLine &`, which I think we can agree is possibly different from `const RailwayLineLink &`. Though given the edit history of the question, it could well be a typo! *(EDIT: Speaking of typos, I made a few here... D'oh!)*

Comment: The questioner isn't clear about which copy constructor is being called unexpectedly: `RailwayLine`, `RailwayLineLink`, or `RailwayLineList`

Comment: I don't think so - take a look at the class that method is defined in, which is also called `RailwayLineList`.

Comment: @Jim, @Platinum:  I think my post is fixed now.

Comment: the constractor that called is

RailwayLine::RailwayLine( const RailwayLine &other)
{
 *this=other;
}

Answer (score 1):

`if (this == NULL)` is technically a valid construct but by the time it's reached, undefined behavior has been generated already if the statement could be true.  DO NOT DO THIS!!!

Comment: This might have been better as a comment or an addendum to an actual answer

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with comparing this to NULL, the behavior leading to this becoming NULL is the actual source of the problem.

Comment: @Jim, comparing `this` to `NULL` indicates a serious logical failure.

Comment: Why downvote the poor guy? +1, Unfortunately I've reached my vote limit for today. @Jim Brissom: I think that's exactly what Noah said.

Comment: @ybungalobill - welcome to SO.  It's better to consider the point system a popularity contest rather than recognition of anything of value.

Comment: @Noah: Yeah, I start to see this. SO is addictive, wastes too much time, sometimes unfair, and gives me almost nothing. Is there a cure from SOmania? I have to retire.

Comment: I didn't downvote this.  But I imagine the reason it was downvoted was because it didn't attempt to answer the question.  Everything @Noah said was correct and valuable, but orthogonal to the OP's question.  It should have been a comment, not an answer.